# Is there a well-defined notion of measure zero on topological manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, geometric-measure-theory

We extend the concept of measure zero on manifolds by local parameterization.
but in this definition we have to check if it is true for every parametrization.
In Guillemin's *Differential Topology* this is stated for differentiable manifolds.

But, what if we just have a topological manifold (i.e., every point has an open neighborhood homeomorphic to some Euclidean space)?  Is measure zero still a well-defined concept in this setting?

Answer (score 9):

No. Just for good old $\mathbb R$, there is a homeomorphism $[0,1]\to[0,1]$ which takes the middle-thirds Cantor set (of measure $0$) to the "fat" [Smith-Volterra-Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) (of measure $1/2$).

(The excluded intervals in the two constructions, including their endpoints, correspond naturally to each other -- simply map each of them to its counterpart interpolating linearly between the endpoints. Then continuity fixes the image of those points of the Cantor set that are *not* interval endpoints).

Answer (score 6):

There are homeomorphisms (see [Henning Makholm's very good answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1252756/155629)) that take a set of zero measure to a set of positive measure (where again measure is taken w.r.t. some local charts), so without modification "measure zero" is not well-defined for topological manifolds. (This pathology is not possible, however, on smooth manifolds.)

On the other hand, Sullivan proved that [any topological manifold of dimension $\neq 4$ has a unique compatible *Lipschitz structure*](http://kssarkaria.org/docs/Sullivan.pdf), that is, a collection of charts whose transition functions are Lipschitz. Lipschitz-ness precludes the sort of pathology described about, so restricting our construction to such a collection yields a well-defined notion of measure zero for topological manifolds (again, except in dimension $4$).